# Simple recursive Summing program

Tags: c++, recursion, mathematics

Any tips on how to improve this simple recursion program?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int findSum(int*, const int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int length = 5, sum = 0, n = 0;
    int list[length];


    for (n; n < length ; n++ )
    {
     list[n] = n + 1; //initializes array elements to 1,2,3,4,5
    }

    n = 0; 

    cout << findSum(list, length, n, sum) << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int findSum(int list[], const int length, int n, int sum)
{
    if (n == length) //if end of list has been reached, stop recursion
    {
        return sum;
    }
    else 
    {
        sum += list[n]; //adds list elements
        n++;            //increments list
        return findSum(list, length, n, sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to improve the recursion or do you want a better technique?

Comment: Recursion must be used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I'd prefer something like this:

```
int findsum(int const *list, int length) { 
    if (0 == length) 
       return 0;
    return list[0] + findsum(list+1, length-1);
}
```

This follows one of the typical recursive formulations -- basically a function that's almost like an inductive proof. Start by establishing a correct value for the simplest possible base case (or some obvious base case anyway), and then establish a pattern that's correct for some some sort of "Base+1" type of case.